# ImporError with 'Hello World' example from Panda3d

Tags: python, panda3d

I just finished installing Panda3d on my Mac, a 3d Python game engine, but when I try to run the hello world example with

```
ppython helloworld.py
```

I get an issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    from direct.showbase.ShoHewBase import ShowBase
  File "dstroot/pythoncode/Developer/Panda3D/lib/direct/showbase/ShowBase.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/Developer/Panda3D/lib/pandac/PandaModules.py", line 8, in <module>
    from libpandaModules import *
  File "/Developer/Panda3D/lib/pandac/libpandaModules.py", line 2, in <module>
    Dtool_PreloadDLL("libpanda")
  File "/Developer/Panda3D/lib/pandac/extension_native_helpers.py", line 79, in Dtool_PreloadDLL
    imp.load_dynamic(module, pathname)
ImportError: dlopen(/Developer/Panda3D/lib/libpanda.dylib, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Cg.framework/Cg
  Referenced from: /Developer/Panda3D/lib/libpanda.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Im assuming that my installation of the engine went wrong, and I am missing the some part of the engine, but I am not really sure how to deal with this issue. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: also, ShoHewBase in line 3 is supposed to be ShowBase.. I typed there by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the "Troubleshooting" section of the Panda3D [Getting-Started](http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Getting_Started_on_OSX) page, you probably need to install the Nvidia Cg toolkit.

Comment: ok. that's a start. its a little embarrassing that i didnt find that, i have to say :D

Comment: well.. there it is.. i guess i just need to read more carefully :D

Comment: I happened to have run into the same problem just a couple of weeks ago so the solution was fresh in my mind. :)